# New ColdFusion 10 Server Instance Won't Start

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a previously installed ColdFusion 10 Multi-server installation that is up and running well. When I create a new instance, via the ColdFusion Administrator, with "Create Windows Service" checked, all seems to go well; the new instance shows up in the Administrator and the new directory structure is created on the server, but the new instance won't start. If I go to the Windows Services panel, on the server, and try to manually start the new service, I get:

```
Windows could not start the ColdFusion 10 Application Server newServer on Local 
Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a 
non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor and refer to the service 
specific error code 2.
```

The Windows System Event log contains the following:

```
The ColdFusion Application Server newServer service terminated with non-specific 
error. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have searched both the web and the Adobe site for a solution, but have come up empty handed. I would appreciate any insight.

Thanks in advance.

**Update from the comments**

Starting the service from the command prompt I see this error:

```
C:\ColdFusion10\newServer\bin>coldfusion.exe -start -console 
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use 
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, 
TRANSPORT_INIT(510) JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): 
No transports initialized [../. ./../src/share/back/debugInit.c:741] 
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, 
jvmtiError=AGENT_E RROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
```

Comment: Check the ColdFusion log files for specific error(s).

Comment: This question is better suited for ServerFault

Comment: As Miguel said, look in the file titled "cfusion-out.log" (or xxx-out.log depending on your install config).  You can also try starting from the command line as a test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error was actually caused by conflicting port numbers in the debugger. Reference ColdFusion Administrator interface ==> Debugging and Logging ==> Debugger Settings. The Debugger Port must be set to a unique value for each server instance. If two or more instances are set to the same value, a port conflict results.

Answer (score 8):

It could be a port conflict issue. You can check the Event Viewer logs. Try the following:-

1. Stop ColdFusion service
2. Launch Command prompt as Administrator
3. Browse to cf_root\cfusion\bin and run the following command coldfusion.exe -start -console
4. Try to access the CF admin, once the services are started.

In case it gives an error message, please share the same.

Comment: Apparently, you're absolutely right. That's a big step in the right direction for me. The error text is  `C:\ColdFusion10\newServer\bin>coldfusion.exe -start -console  
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use  
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)  
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../.
./../src/share/back/debugInit.c:741]  
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_E
RROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)`

Comment: Open the server.xml file at C:\ColdFusion10\<instance_name>\runtime\conf and check the Connector port & shutdown port. Use netstat –ano to get the list of ports and check, if there is a port conflict

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. First, if you are in a windows environment use

> netstat -ano

to get a list of ports in use. Then, open 
c:\ColdFusion11{instancename}\bin\jvm.config and find the port address in your JVM arguments, if the port isn't unique, change it to one that is. Then fire up CF from the command line like this:

> c:\coldfusion11{instancename}\bin\coldfusion.exe -start -console

Should now start properly or indicate if there is still a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to my local Dev install after a system update. I just tried changing the default port from 8500 to 8501 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can save someone else from the frustration I faced with some update I didn't explicitly authorize.... this was the cause and fix for my scenario...

JRE version On PC was updated and out of sync with CF settings JRE version...

[JRE on PC and CF Settings out of sync...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qMll.png)

Solution: updated the jvm.config file to have the same JRE version number as the version on my PC, started CF services, and Bob's your uncle.